# Extract Top level Elements Name attribute from XSD using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, xslt-2.0

I need to extract root element name attribute my input is as below

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
    <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:nxsd="http://xmlns"   nxsd:encoding="US-ASCII">
        <xsd:element name="car">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="wheel" type="xsd:string" />
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:appinfo>NXSDSAMPLE=</xsd:appinfo>
            <xsd:appinfo>USEHEADER=false</xsd:appinfo>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:schema>
```

The XSL looks like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="/*/*[local-name()='element']">
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"></xsl:value-of>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The required output is only "car" but the transformation is generating

```
      NXSDSAMPLE=
      USEHEADER=false
car
```

My program looks like below

```
 Document document;
  DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
  File rootNameStyleSheet = new File("RootElementNameExtractor.xsl");
  File datafile = new File("cf1.xsd");
  try {
      DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
      document = builder.parse(datafile);
      TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
      StreamSource stylesource = new StreamSource(rootNameStyleSheet);
      Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(stylesource);
      transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
      transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, indent);
      DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
      StreamResult result = new StreamResult(sw);
      transformer.transform(source, result);
}
```

Any inputs on what is wrong with XSL would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write a stylesheet that simply does

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select="/*/xsd:element[1]/@name"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: thank you for the xsl ,the xsl is pulling out the root element name as expected , but when there are more than one elements , it pulls out all the element names , how to get only the 1st element name.

Comment: That's what the `[1]` does: it selects the first one only.

Answer (score 1):

There are built-in templates that ensure that processing starts at the root node and then applies further templates to the child nodes. That way your template is finally used, but your other input nodes are processed as well by built-in templates.

You have two options, either add

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="xsd:schema/xsd:element"/>
</xsl:template>
```

(assumes your stylesheet declares `xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"`) or make sure you override built-in templates for text node output with

```
<xsl:template match="text()"/>
```